# Magento2- How to Filter Multiple Values in Column

Tags: magento2, extensions, grid, grid-layout

There is multiselect customer group field in form of my custom module and those values are displayed in grid with comma seperated
Ex.

```
      Customer group 
      General, Wholesaler
      retailer
```

If we choose **retailer** then it filtered results but if we select **General or wholesaler** then it won't and I know I have to do some customization to filter results for multiple values but how can I implement it?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Please write in detail with Your applied code (PHP CODE)

Comment: @keith can you please share the code, if you got a solution?